# Parsing XML in D

Tags: xml, d

I'm trying to parse a XML document that stores data for a map in my 2D game. I'm trying to take this step by step, I've loaded the file, create a new document parser, and picked a start tag and attribute I want to pull. However when I check to see what the value of the attribute should be (25) it comes out as zero. Telling me that i'm missing something and it's not pulling the XML value.

This is the XML file being parsed: http://pastebin.com/tpUU1Wtv

```
    void LoadMap(string filename)
{
    enforce( filename != "" , "Filename is invalid!" );

    xmlData = cast(string) read(filename);

    enforce( xmlData != "", "Read file Failed!" );

}

void ParseMap()
{
    auto xml = new DocumentParser(xmlData);

    xml.onStartTag["map"] = (ElementParser e)
    {
        mapWidth = to!int(e.tag.attr["width"]);
    };
    xml.parse();
    writeln("Map Width: ", mapWidth);
}
```

Comment: and if you don't convert to `int` what does `e.tag.attr["width"]` hold (and what other attr are there)

Comment: It holds an empty string as far as writeln is concerned. Under the map tag: <map version="1.0" orientation="orthogonal" width="25" height="19" tilewidth="32" tileheight="32">

Comment: Maybe add "e.parse();" after "mapWidth = ..." line? as in http://dlang.org/phobos/std_xml.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current xml module seems to be a bit buggy, an alternative is being worked on, I believe.

The reason your code doesn't work is that for some reason the parser ignores the outer, enclosing tag. Which in your case is "map". If you wrap your map tag in a dummy tag, then suddenly it does work.

```
<dummy>
   <map...>
    ...
   </map>
</dummy>
```

Comment: The alternative (which will probably become std.xml2) is located here: http://dsource.org/projects/xmlp Using that is probly less frustrating than working around bugs in std.xml.

Comment: 2017, now std.xml still buggy, so there only I without believe.

Answer (score 1):

Is using YAML an option? D-YAML?

Comment: I'm not sure what that is. I ended up using a custom XML library because of the bug fwend was talking about.

Comment: YAML Ain't Markup Language. It's a nice, human & machine readable alternative to XML